# Show functionally completeness property for propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Let $n>0, n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and let t,f denote true and false.
>
> For every function
>
> $$g:\{t,f \}^n \to \{t,f\} $$ There is a propositional forumala $B$,
>   using only the connectives $\neg, \wedge$ and built up from  from the
>   atomic formulas $P_1,\ldots, P_n$ such that for every truth assignment
>   $$\mathcal{A}:\{P_1,\ldots, P_n\}\to \{t,f \}$$
>
> $$A\models B \text{ if and only if } g(\mathcal{A}(P_1),\ldots ,
> > \mathcal{A}(P_1)) = t$$

I don't really know how to prove this. I understand that I somehow must code the above as a formula and then "reducing" it to a equivalent formula consisting only of $\neg, \wedge$ using well known equivalences and then prove the above with induction. I don't really where to start. Any help or references to where this is proved in detail would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).

Comment: I believe you mean $n \in \mathbb{N}$..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proof naturally goes as an induction on $n$:

(*Basis Case*) Let $n=1$. It suffices to show that there is a formula consisting of $\neg, \wedge$ with the all possible unary connectives defined by the following 4 truth tables:

$$\begin{array} {|c|}
\hline
P & \neg(P\wedge\neg P) \\ \hline
1 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}
\begin{array} {|c|}
\hline
P & P \\ \hline
1 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}
\begin{array} {|c|}
\hline
P & \neg P \\ \hline
1 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}
\begin{array} {|c|}
\hline
P & P\wedge\neg P \\ \hline
1 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

(*Inductive Case*) Inductive Hypothesis: Suppose that for every $n$-ary connective defined by its valuation function, there are formulae consisting of $\neg, \wedge$. We need to show that for every $n+1$-ary connectives, propositions have been found. (Can you continue from here?)